# On mkuserlocation, how do I show my own custom message in viewForAnnotation

Tags: ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to show a custom message instead of "My Location" in viewForAnnotation.  How do I do this?

Thanks
Deshawn

Answer (score 2):

In the delegate of your `MKMapView`, implement the method `mapView:viewForAnnotation` and check if the annotation is of type `MKUserLocation`. If yes, change the title and subtitle properties of the annotation. The callout will automatically pull the new values. Or you can create a totally new view and return it here.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        annotation.title = @"I am here";
        return nil;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code.

Comment: Hi, You cannot set the title directly like that... is there any other way to set the title of this annotation?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by updating `Title` property of `MKUserLocation`.

As `MKAnnotation` protocol doesn't require making `Title` a property, cast annotation passed as an argument to `MKUserLocation` and set the property

```
- (MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:    (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        [(MKUserLocation*)annotation setTitle: @"I am here"];
        return nil;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply referring directly to it works too, like this...

```
mapView.userLocation.title = @"I am here";
```

This can be done from anywhere you have a reference to the map view.