# How can the MKUserLocation be programmatically selected?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Titles and subtitles can be added to the user location that iOS shows using [MKUserLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400880/on-mkuserlocation-how-do-i-show-my-own-custom-message-in-viewforannotation). When the user taps on the location, these will show in a bubble above the location. The thought bubbles for other annotations can be shown by selecting the annotation with `setSelected:animated:` from MKAnnotationView. Unfortunately, MKUserLocation does not descend from MKAnnotationView.

How can I programmatically select the user location so the annotation appears over the user location without the user first tapping on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `MKAnnotationView` says this about its `setSelected:animated:` method (and something similar for its `selected` property):

> You should not call this method directly.

Instead, use the `MKMapView` method `selectAnnotation:animated:`.  If you call it in the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method, you can be sure the annotation view is ready to show the callout otherwise calling `selectAnnotation` will do nothing.

For example:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    for (MKAnnotationView *av in views)
    {
        if ([av.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            [mapView selectAnnotation:av.annotation animated:NO];
            //Setting animated to YES for the user location 
            //gives strange results so setting it to NO.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. Incidentally, the comment about strange results if animation is used is spot-on. In my app, animation causes the user location to reset tot he north pole (roughly). With no animation, things work as expected.