# Current location title? Mapkit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit

I'm making an application with MapKit. Here's an image of how it looks:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt7Qg.png]

And I want to change (Current location) title of the symbol current location from that pin.

[image: LINK in comment because of reputation]

Here's code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,    MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var theMap: MKMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    let location = self.locationManager.location

    var latitude: Double = location.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude: Double = location.coordinate.longitude

    println("GPS Súradnice :: \(latitude), \(longitude)")

    theMap.delegate = self
    theMap.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
    theMap.showsUserLocation = true


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}



//--- Find Address of Current Location ---//

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    //--- CLGeocode to get address of current location ---//
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in



        if (error != nil)
        {
            println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0
        {
            let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })

}


func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark?)
{
    if let Placemark = placemark
    {
        //Stop updating kvôli vydrži baterke
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let adresa = (Placemark.thoroughfare != nil) ? Placemark.thoroughfare : "Ulica: "
        let cislo = (Placemark.subThoroughfare != nil) ? Placemark.subThoroughfare : "Číslo ulice:"
        let mesto = (Placemark.locality != nil) ? Placemark.locality : "Mesto: "
        let stat = (Placemark.country != nil) ? Placemark.country : "Štát: "


        var coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark!.location.coordinate

        var pointAnnotation:MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pointAnnotation.coordinate = coordinates
        pointAnnotation.title = "\(adresa) \(cislo)"
        pointAnnotation.subtitle = "\(adresa) \(cislo), \(mesto), \(stat)"


        self.theMap.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
        self.theMap.centerCoordinate = coordinates
        self.theMap.selectAnnotation(pointAnnotation, animated: true)

        println(mesto)
        println(adresa)
        println(cislo)
        println(stat)

    }

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
{
    println("Chyba pri aktualizovaní lokácie " + error.localizedDescription)
}




}
```

Comment: Do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6464019/467105

Comment: yes. But It's in Objective-C and I'm beginner so I think I don't know to convert it

Comment: Try it and then update your question with what you tried and the exact problem or error.  By the way, post screenshots as small as possible and only showing the relevant parts instead of giant, full size resolution.

Comment: oh.. Now I'm looking.. Isn't it a Pin?

Comment: Cool story bro! You post a couple of giant screen-shots and a bunch of code? What is your question? How does the code that you posted relate to your question?

Comment: As you say, isn't what you posted just a pin on the map in addition to the current location blue dot? What are you trying to do that's different than standard map kit behavior?

Comment: I'm trying to change title from the symbol of current location (blue dot) to address like in Pin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I get it right. You want to change blue dot. Try this.

```
let theLocation: MKUserLocation = theMap.userLocation
theLocation.title = "I'm here!"
```

Answer (score 1):

//swift 3

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = center
annotation.title = "title"
Annotation.subtitle = “Subtitle”
mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

I think,http://swift3devlopment.blogspot.in/ here you get more details of MapKit

Answer (score -1):

For Show blue circle mapkit in swift 2.0:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    //this line show blue circle location user
    Mapa.showsUserLocation = true

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else{
        print("Location service disabled");
    }

}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locValue, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    Mapa.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```